# How to Python automatic language detection from SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Python needs to automatically recognize the language of the audio file being loaded and print the text from the audio file in a specific language when the user clicks the Transcribe button, whether this is possible and what the function should look like, please help.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    transcript = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("FORM DATA RECEIVED")

        if "file" not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            audioFile = sr.AudioFile(file)
            with audioFile as source:
                data = recognizer.record(source)

            transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language="en-US")

    return render_template('index.html', transcript=transcript)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Ok, I created in the HTML drop down list, but how do I link it to get the result of the `transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language="en-US")` selected language in the line?

```
<label for="lang">Language:</label>
  <select name="lang" id="langs">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="es">Spanis</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
  </select>
```

---

FULL TEMPLATE:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)


def get_languages():
    url = 'https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    start_text = '        <tbody class="list">\n'
    end_text = '        </tbody>\n'
    table = resp.text.split(start_text)[1].split(end_text)[0]
    tr_start = '          <tr>\n'
    sections = table.split(tr_start)[1:]
    languages = []

    for section in sections:
        short = section.splitlines()[1].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        long = section.splitlines()[0].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        if len(languages) > 0:
            # dupe check. For some reason the page has all
            # languages twice
            if languages[-1] != {'short': short, 'long': long}:
                languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
        else:
            languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
    print(f'FOUND {len(languages)} LANGUAGES')
    return languages


language_list = get_languages()


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    transcript = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("FORM DATA RECEIVED")
        # set the language, use en-US by default
        language = request.form.get('langs') or 'en-US'

        if "file" not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            audioFile = sr.AudioFile(file)
            with audioFile as source:
                data = recognizer.record(source)

            # change the line below
            transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language)

    return render_template('index.html', transcript=transcript, language_list=language_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: You're talking about a universal translator.  That technology does not exist.  Speech recognition is hard enough when you KNOW the language being spoken.  Maybe you can do the research to make that happen.

Comment: For example, I have an audio file in Spanish, currently this script only recognizes English, I need that when loading an audio file in Spanish, the automatic Python recognizes Spanish.

Comment: Right.  I understand completely what you're asking.  If you KNOW the file is in Spanish and pass that information along with the file, you can select the right language in your script.  But the technology to listen to a file and figure out what language it is simply does not exist, except in Star Trek.

Answer (score 0):

### **EDIT**

You might want to move the method `get_languages()` to another py file, run it once to save the `language_list` to a JSON, and include the JSON in your Flask app so you can load it from there, instead of having to do the request each time the Flask app starts.

### **getlanguages.py**

```py
import requests
import json


def get_languages():
    url = 'https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    start_text = '        <tbody class="list">\n'
    end_text = '        </tbody>\n'
    table = resp.text.split(start_text)[1].split(end_text)[0]
    tr_start = '          <tr>\n'
    sections = table.split(tr_start)[1:]
    languages = []

    for section in sections:
        short = section.splitlines()[1].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        long = section.splitlines()[0].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        if len(languages) > 0:
        # dupe check
            if languages[-1] != {'short': short, 'long': long}:
                languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
        else:
            languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
    print(f'FOUND {len(languages)} LANGUAGES')
    return languages


with open('languages.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(get_languages(), outfile, indent=4)
```

### **app.py**

Remove the function and replace the assignment to `language_list` with the code below.

```py
with open('languages.json') as infile:
    language_list = json.load(infile)
```

---

### **OLD ANSWER**

---

I had some code for a personal project that might be useful for you. It performs a request on [the page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages) that contains all languages that the speech API can handle, and extracts the full language name and the BCP-47 code. You can use this with a template for loop to create the dropdown list.

Then it's just getting the variable from the form submit and pass the language variable to the speech API. I added 1 line of code in `index()` and changed the way the transcript is generated.

### **main.py**

The `get_languages()` method needs to be called before the app is instantiated in the dunder main...

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)


def get_languages():
    url = 'https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    start_text = '        <tbody class="list">\n'
    end_text = '        </tbody>\n'
    table = resp.text.split(start_text)[1].split(end_text)[0]
    tr_start = '          <tr>\n'
    sections = table.split(tr_start)[1:]
    languages = []

    for section in sections:
        short = section.splitlines()[1].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        long = section.splitlines()[0].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        if len(languages) > 0:
            # dupe check. For some reason the page has all
            # languages twice
            if languages[-1] != {'short': short, 'long': long}:
                languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
        else:
            languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
    print(f'FOUND {len(languages)} LANGUAGES')
    return languages


language_list = get_languages()


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    transcript = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("FORM DATA RECEIVED")
        # set the language, use en-US by default
        language = request.form.get('lang') or 'en-US'
        print(f'SELECTED LANGUAGE: {language}')

        if "file" not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            audioFile = sr.AudioFile(file)
            with audioFile as source:
                data = recognizer.record(source)

            # change the line below
            transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language)

    return render_template('index.html', transcript=transcript, language_list=language_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

### **template**

change your template section to this

```
<label for="lang">Language:</label>
    <select name="lang" id="langs">
        {% for lan in language_list %}
            <option value="{{ lan.short }}">{{ lan.long }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I run the code, it only prints English, it doesn't recognize other languages, what's the problem?

Comment: can you put the full template you're using in the question?

Comment: So, two things: I had a typo in the `language = request.form.get('lang') or 'en-US'`. I was using `langs` instead of `lang`. I've edited my code. Second thing is that in your template you have the select dropdown outside of the form tags. You need to move that inside the form tags so it becomes part of the form...

Comment: I made another edit, to move the generation of the language list to a separate py file, and to simply load the JSON in the Flask app that the other py file generates...

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you :-)